# Is it not guaranteed that all statements gets executed in a goroutine?

Tags: go, goroutine

There is no error when I run the following code, but nothings gets printed either:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    counter := 0
    for {
        
        select {
        case c <- x:
            fmt.Println("sent x", x)
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
        
        counter += 1
        fmt.Println("Counter", (counter));
        
    }
    
    fmt.Println("Fib exiting");
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("got" , <-c)
        }
        quit <- 0
        fmt.Println("Anon exiting");
    }()
    go fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

I was thinking at least `"Fib exiting"` should be printed. If I execute `fibonacci()` normally in the main goroutine, it works.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not guaranteed that all statements gets executed in a goroutine?

All statements that should execute according to your program control flow will execute.

Your `fmt.Println("Fib exiting")` print call doesn't execute because `main()` is returning immediately after spawning the two goroutines.

However even if `main()` were properly synchronized, `fmt.Println("Fib exiting")` is still unreachable code, because the `select` statement in `fibonacci()` either sends on `c` or receives on `quit`, and neither of those cases break out of the loop.

Comment: Just curious , what happens to the launched go routines after main exits ?